# can I transfer a software installed in my ubuntu to other ubuntu laptop?

Tags: 15.04, offline

At my home I don't get very fast internet. So I want to use the softwares installed in my friend's Ubuntu 15.04 on my Ubuntu 15.04 Laptop. Is there some way I could do this, or some other possible way I could achieve my objective?

Most of the computers around me are Windows systems. Can I download full software in windows then install it in ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe something like resume feature while installing might help. can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download it on your friend's Laptop with `apt-get download (NAMEOFPACKAGEHERE)` and you will get the `deb` file used to install the package which can be installed with `sudo dpkg -i (NAMEOFPACKAGEHERE).deb` on your computer.

As for downloading on Windows computers you can browse [the APT repo](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/).

Another option is checking in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` for the `deb` file for the program you want to install.

Also you could use the APT repo in a [(*MUCH*) prettier format](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/)

Comment: Not very useful, as downloading a package does not take care of its dependencies.

Comment: Well, I tried. At least this is portable throughout all systems  with APT

Comment: which file to download in aptrepo. Its pretty confusing

Comment: :) Yeah I know. Click the first letter of the program you want (i.e. G for GZIP), then click the name (For libraries usually click the program they are for) of the program (GZIP for GZIP), then click the file with this format: NAME_VERSIONubuntu1_architecture.deb (for gzip at the time of writing this is gzip_1.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

Comment: I want to download kile and ns-3. I searched for kile in k directory its not there and neither is ns3 in n.

Comment: Check out [the pretty one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/)

Comment: I found ns3 there but its size is only 500kb whereas in software centere its 1 Gb

Comment: kile is not there. (kile is a latex development enviornment)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you have the names right of all the programs you want to install and ensure they are in the repositories. Then open a terminal and list off the programs you wish to install as seen below. You could also mark all programs you wish to install in Synaptic Package Manager. Then I would set your computer to not sleep or hibernate, and simply start the process when you go to bed one night, and hopefully it would be done by the time you wake up the next morning. In terminal, if the process gets interrupted due to internet connectivity, you can just run the same command again, and it picks up where it left off.

```
sudo apt-get install program1 program2 program3 program4 -y
```